# Review audit which seems like a possible answer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Today I was reviewing low quality posts and I came across the answer for this question.

**[How to read the flash card Android on Mac OS? Error "the disk not readable by this computer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060134/how-to-read-the-flash-card-android-on-mac-os-error-the-disk-not-readable-by-th)**

The OP states that after formatting a flash drive and connecting it to Mac device, he get's the error

> The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.

Now here is the answer to that question (which was apparently an audit):

[image]

Why is this marked as an audit? The OP has problems with a possible corrupted device and the answer guides him how to initialize a repair through Disk Utility. I'm not saying that this might fix the OP's problem, but it's definitely worth a try and it's on topic.

Comment: It surprises me that *Community* casted that spam flag. IMO thats not spammy at all.

Comment: The question is off-topic and should probably not have been answered. But I don't see any reason why the answer was spam deleted.

Comment: Perhaps the answer was from a spam account or one deleted for offensive content? Or there was a spam link/offensive content that was removed? Not sure. It's yet another review that shouldn't be one yet was automatically chosen as one. I wonder if we need a way to report the reviews directly in the UI there. Manual vetting of all the audits would probably be better but it would also be a lot harder to maintain in shape (yet another review queue?), so perhaps there can at least be a "Flag this audit for review" if it's "new" (automatically chosen, not manually approved), for these situations.

Comment: Even if the answer was from the spam account, I was reviewing the post, not the account, and the post seemed as a possible answer. I only got 2 days block but it should definitely be handled in a better way.

Comment: It was spam-deleted by a moderator, @Jonas. Community is always shown as the deletion user in the case of spam or rude/abusive flags, even when they're cast by a human moderator. The user was definitely a spammer. The spam links appeared in comments underneath the answer, which have now been deleted, so normal users can't see them. Either way, I agree this is not a great audit candidate.

Comment: For future reference, Dino, the correct course of action here would have been to flag the clearly off-topic question for closure, and "Skip" the review of the answer since you've handled the problem at the source (the off-topic question).

Comment: @codyGray that makes sense, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: OK...other than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24250965), I don't see any issues with your recent reviews, so I'm going to go ahead and lift that ban and mark this as a duplicate of another Q&A where essentially the same thing happened and Jean-Francois resolved it in the same way. Regarding what you should learn from this, see my comment above. Whenever the system cautions you that something might be spam, *always* look more carefully. In this case, you would have noticed that the question is off-topic, and you could have dealt with that.

Comment: @codyGray Thanks for explaining, I will definitely keep an eye on it from now on.